# How do i receive data

Tags: java, udp

My listener ->

```java
    public void startListening(){
        String[] details = session.split(":");
        SessionUser user = new SessionUser();
        System.out.println("Waiting for another user..");
        listening = new Thread("listen thread"){
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    while (user.users < 2) {
                        try {
                            Socket socket1 = socket.accept();
                            System.out.println(socket1.getInetAddress().toString() + " has joined...");
                            user.users++;
                            socket1.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("Ran into a error!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        listening.start();

    }
```

My sender ->

```java
    public void join(InetAddress address, int port){
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, address, port);
        try {
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
            System.out.println("Attempting to join session <" + address.toString() + ":" + port + ">!");
            socket.send(packet);
            System.out.println("Joining......");
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Unable to connect, this may be a server error, or you've entered incorrect details!");
        }
    }
```

So i just want to send packets to the hosts server upon connecting, however, when i run this i am not seeing any sort of output, here is a picture that will probably explain it better then i can -> [click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUREl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your server to receive the packets as well

```
DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
serverSocket.receive(packet); // This will block until a packet is received
System.out.println("Received: " + new String(packet.getData()));
```

Try testing with your client

```
public void join(InetAddress address, int port){
        byte[] data = "Hello".getBytes();
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, address, port);
        try {
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
            System.out.println("Attempting to join session <" + address.toString() + ":" + port + ">!");
            socket.send(packet);
            System.out.println("Joining......");
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Unable to connect, this may be a server error, or you've entered incorrect details!");
        }
}
```

If you need to maintain a connection, it's better to use TCP with Sockets.

Comment: So i was messing around with the receiver and i came up with this ->

Comment: https://hastebin.com/opazopixot.cs

However, now im getting this error -> 
https://hastebin.com/itopeledex.css

Comment: Change the port and close all processes that were running before. You can't use the same port for both.

Create only one Socket for listening, you are trying to create one everytime in the loop.

Comment: i forgot to remove it from the loop, but i figured i had to use 1 port for listening and connecting

Answer (score 1):

In your receiver, you're reading from a TCP socket, whereas your sender is sending an UDP packet. This cannot work.

Comment: Oh, thanks so much, i was just coding from the top of my head, appreciate it!